# Creating categories in a ListView?

Tags: android, listview, categories

How do I create categories in an arbitrary ListView like those in Preferences (PreferenceCategory)?

I've found `android.R.layout.preference_category` that renders that grey TextView but don't see it mentioned anywhere from java code.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> > How do I create categories in an arbitrary ListView like those in
> >     Preferences (PreferenceCategory)?
> >     I've found android.R.layout.preference_category
> >     that renders that grey
> >     TextView but don't see it mentioned anywhere from java code.
>
> http://jsharkey.org/blog/2008/08/18/separating-lists-with-headers-in-android-09/
>
> Note that the code is from Android 0.9
>   and may require minor modifications to
>   work in Android 1.5.
>
> I have an Android 1.5-compatible
>   variant on his code up at:
>
> http://commonsware.com/AdvAndroid/
>
> (scroll down, click on the Source Code
>   link, and look at the
>   ListView/Sections project)
>
> --  Mark Murphy (a Commons Guy) http://commonsware.com
>   *The Busy Coder's Guide to Android Development* Version 2.0 Available!

Thanks, Mark!

Comment: Did you have Android2.2 variant version of SectionedAdapter ?